# Is there an equivalent to a 'quarter' for twelfths?

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

> I've heard of quintants, septants, octants, and quandrants, but I can't find a word for a sector of a twelfths. Any ideas?

> (Assumed example: "The third ___________ of the sky contains the constellation of Aires." added by Greybeard 20221112)

Comment: Maybe it’s a ***month***  ;-)

Comment: *Twelfth* already seems like the equivalent of *quarter* to me. *I ate a **quarter** of the pie* and *I ate a **twelfth** of the pie.* What am I missing?

Comment: What Jason said -- what do you think is wrong with "a twelfth"?

Comment: @JasonBassford, HotLicks, a fourth matches a twelfth.  A half and a quarter are different.

Comment: @jim In what way is a *fourth* different from a *quarter* when looking at the senses in which they are synonymous? And are you saying that two fourths do *not* make a *half*? If not, what do they make?

Comment: @Jim A fourth is almost never used in British English (not relevant, maybe, but interesting!)

Comment: In ordinals, the PROPER terms are "wonth", "tooth", "threeth", "forth", "fifeth", "sickth", "seventh", "ateth", "neinth", "tinth", ...  All those other authorities are wrong!!

Comment: Latin had words for all the twelfths: *uncia, sextant–, quadrant–, trient–, quincunc–, semiss–, septunc–, bess–, dodrant–, dextant–, deunc–*.  (All but *uncia* are consonant stems.)

Comment: The text of the question shows that the the OP wants the analogue not to "quarter" but to "quadrant". As @JasonBassford said, the analogue of "quarter" is "twelfth". Fact is, the only words English has for appropriately-sized sectors of a circle are quadrant, sextant and octant. (And semicircle, if you count that.) Fact is, the language does not have a single word for every concept. If you make a word up, people wouldn't know what you meant. In the interests of letting your readers understand you, I suggest "30° sector".

Comment: How about a "dozenth"??

Answer (score 3):

Most of the "sector" terms you refer to are derived from Latin. The equivalent for a twelfth would be something like ***duodectant***, from the Latin *duodecimus* (twelfth).

But I'd not expect many English speakers to understand what you meant. A few might work it out from knowledge of Latin (not common), and a few more might connect it with some other 12-related word like *dodecahedron* (which is from Greek rather than Latin, so not an exact root match).

So you'd mostly be making up a new word, and needing to explain its meaning to anyone you spoke it to. In some contexts, coining neologisms is fine, and as long as you explain yourself the first time you use the word, you could then go on to use it repeatedly, and perhaps achieve more clarity than if you kept needing to say "a twelfth of a circle." But if you're only going to mention it once, or if you're speaking or writing in a context where linguistic creativity is frowned upon, you might just annoy the people you're communicating with.

Answer (score 1):

> I've heard of quintants, septants, octants, and quadrants, but I can't find a word for a sector of a twelfths. Any ideas?
>
> (Assumed example: "The third ___________ of the sky contains the constellation of Aires.")

Yes, there isn't one that follows the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A [*quarter*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quarter) is AFAIK a far more colloquial and commonplace synonym for a [*fourth*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fourth). Both words (as corroborated by Collins) denote a fraction, namely *"one of four equal parts of something"*; be it tangible or abstract, I should add: *a quarter of the pie*, just like *a quarter of an hour*, or even *a quarter of what I've said*...

In this sense, the word [*twelfth*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/twelfth), as suggested by @JasonBassford and @HotLicks, is a perfectly valid equivalent, denoting *one of twelve equal parts* of something:

> *She is entitled to a twelfth of the cash.*

Note that HotLick's [*dozenth*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dozenth) is also valid, albeit scantly used, I would guess.

This seems to be what the OP is asking for in the title:

> Is there an equivalent to a 'quarter'...?

---

However, if what the OP actually is looking for is the equivalent of a [*quadrant*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quadrant), which is specifically one of four equal parts of a disk (a *circular sector*), then I guess you could call it a ***half-sextant***, or a ***semi-sextant***, if you're in the mood for Latin.

Usage examples seem to come from niched scientific contexts, but then again, where else could such a word be needed?

Quoting one for each variant:

> *In comparison with the previous reports which require the calculation of
> the switching angles in the first sextant, only the switching angles in
> the first **half sextant** are required*. [[source](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/647677)]

> *As the Subtense of a Quadrant, to the Subtense of a Trient wanting the
> Radius; so is the Radius, to the Subtense of the **Semi-sextant**...*
> [[source](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A67419.0001.001/1:2?rgn=div1;view=fulltext)]

Of course, the word *sextant* also has a different, more common meaning, but my guess is that context will suffice to elucidate that you're not talking about measuring instruments.

E.g.

> The third *half-sextant* of the sky contains the constellation of
> Aires.

In other, simpler words:

> The third *twelfth* of the sky contains the constellation of
> Aires.

Answer (score -4):

The word **dodecafid** means 1/12 or twelfth i.e. divisible into twelve parts or regions.

Reference link 1: [allhotelscalifornia.com](http://www.allhotelscalifornia.com/kokogiakcom/logolepsy/ow_d.html#dodecafid)

Reference link 2: [Wordnik.com](https://www.wordnik.com/words/dodecafid)

Citation from the book: [Three Toed Sloths and Seven League Boots: A Dictionary of Numerical Expressions](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=2FyBdsRfTkwC&q=%22dodecafid%22&dq=%22dodecafid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj678G0-sHhAhUJurwKHQryAiEQ6AEIPjAD)

Comment: After reading the definitions I belleve that *dodecafid* does not mean 1/12 or twelfth.  It means divisible into twelve parts.  In other words it refers to the whole rather than the resultant pieces.  Supposing an orange had twelve segments, the orange could be called a dodecafid not the segments themselves.  I think OP would like to say something like: “There’s 12 of us, let’s each take a dodecafid of the treasure.”  In my estimation that’s not how this word is used.